# WooCommerce: how to add suffix to attribute value?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

We are building a wine-shop and have a few typical attributes like alcohol, sugar, acid that have values. These attributes are measured in units - e.g. alcohol in vol.%, sugar in g/litre, etc.
The "additional information" tab shows the attribute names and values but just the values without the unit right after.
Consequently we want to add a suffix for each attribute via a snippet/hook in functions.php and have tried with below code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', 'custom_attribute_label', 10, 3 );
function custom_attribute_label( $label, $name, $product ) {
    $taxonomy = 'pa_'.$name;
    if( $taxonomy == 'alk' )
        $label .= '<span class="custom-label"> vol.%</span>';
    return $label;
}
```

but this does not generate any output on frontend.

Any ideas and/or feedback to solve/tweak this are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be `if ( $taxonomy === 'pa_alk' )`

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't change anything - the label suffix text is still not displayed.

Comment: it probably means that the attribute name already has the prefix 'pa_' 
 so, try to remove this line "$taxonomy = 'pa_' . $name;"
If it fails, then try adding "echo $name;" before the condition to check the attribute name

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code, now it's working:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', 'custom_attribute_label', 10, 3);
function custom_attribute_label( $label, $taxonomy, $product ) {
if( $taxonomy == 'pa_alk' )
    $label .= '<span class="custom-label"> vol.%</span>';
return $label;
}
```